# Compare A String from A Column of Values in VBA Access

Tags: function, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hi I am new with VBA Access and I am wondering if someone can help me with this.

I have this column in TableA in Access:

**Inventory**
999ABCDEF
123GHIJKL
456MNOPQR
789STUVWX

I have this column in TableB:

**ShortCode**
123
845
999
789

I would need to compare each Inventory with all the values of the ShortCode column. If the first three letters of each Inventory is in the ShortCode table, return "YES" and if not "NO"

This is my code so far.

Hopefully someone can help me.

```
Option Compare Database

Function getLeftSide(Inventory As String, ShortCode As String)
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set fld = dbs.OpenRecordset(Sheet1).Fields(ShortCode)


    getLeftSide = Left([Inventory], 3)

    getLeftSide = StrComp([getLeftSide], [ShortCode])
       getLeftSide = "yes"
    Else
       getLeftSide = "no"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code so far? What does it do that it shouldn't be doing?

Comment: @dbmitch I am new to vba and was wondering if i can get some guidance as to where I can proceed with my code to get my results

Comment: You are close now. How many rows are in your short code table? And how many rows get compared from your long code table? I think it would almost be worth it to read all your short codes into an array when the form loads. Then the comparisons would be lightning fast. Otherwise I'd set up a parameter query that takes short code as it's only parameter. Both methods would return results quickly. A querydef code solution is simpler.

Comment: @dbmitch I have 80 rows on my ShortCode table. And I have at least 800,000 on my long code table(Inventory). I'm not doing it on a form, I just need a field that says "YES" if getLeftSide = Left([Inventory], 3) is in ShortCode and "NO" if not

Comment: Okay - that's important information to have in your question. Is this a one-time query that you want to update all your Inventory rows - or is it going be ad-hoc query - like your example - where you just pass in a long code and get a yes/no back for the one row?

Comment: @dbmitch it's just like my example. and once done correctly, getting the "YES" and "NO", the query wont be changed

Comment: Added answer - let me know if it fits the bill

Comment: @dbmitch what happens to this " Left([Inventory], 3)" cause I have to get the left side of Inventory to be able to compare it with the short code. Also, where would i call getLeftSide? in a separate query?

Comment: Sure - updated the answer to include that. You can call it wherever you need it - if you have VBA code or in a query. If you're going to do it in a query, just replace the strInventoryCode parameter with the field name [InventoryCode] - as in `InShortCodeTable:getLeftSide([Inventory])`

Answer (score 2):

All you should have to do is create a query extending your inventory rows by an additional column for the `prefix = left(inventoryID,3)` and then in a second query, `outer join` those results with your `shortCode` table.  If the result is null (prefix not found in shortCode,) then return No, else Yes.

Comment: I am new with VBA, and I am wondering if you can show me a sample of how the code works? If I should change anything on my code

Comment: Don't use vba, create a query with an additional column for your derived prefix field, then create a second query using the first to outer join with your table.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this, but the way you described your problem this should be the simplest solution that has minimal future maintenance, and is easiest to modify.

- Create New Query
- Open SQL View

**Paste this (replace TableB with your actual table name)**

`PARAMETERS [What Code] Text ( 255 );
 SELECT TableB.ShortCode
 FROM TableB
 WHERE [TableB].[ShortCode]=[What Code];`

**Save Query As:** `qdfGetShortCode`

> **Then use this function in your module:**

```
Public Function getLeftSide(strInventoryCode As String) As String

    Const SHORTCODE_QUERY   As String = "qdfGetShortCode"

    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qdf         As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strCode     As String

    strCode = Left$(strInventoryCode, 3)

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(SHORTCODE_QUERY)
    qdf.Parameters("What Code") = strCode
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    If rs.EOF Then
       getLeftSide = "no"
    Else
       getLeftSide = "yes"
    End If
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing

End Function
```

> **How to use it:**

You can call it wherever you need it - if you have VBA code or in a query.
If you're going to do it in a query, just replace the strInventoryCode parameter with the field name [InventoryCode] - as in `InShortCodeTable:getLeftSide([Inventory])`

Answer (score -1):

Add a field [test] to tablea

```
Sub shortcodetest()  
Dim rs as dao.recordset  
Dim rs2 as dao.recordset  
Set  rs = currentdb.openrecordset("TableA", dbopendynaset)  
Set rs2 = currentdb.openrecordset("TableB", dbopendynaset)  
Do   
Rs.movefirst  
Rs2.findfirst "[shortcode] = " & chr(34) & left(rs("inventory"),3) & chr(34)  
Rs.edit  
If rs2.nomatch = true then  
Rs("test") = "no"  
Else  
rs("test") = "yes"  
End if  
Rs.update  
Rs.movenext  
Loop until rs.eof  
Rs.close  
Rs2.close  
End sub
```